# Elasticsearch painless error index_out_of_bounds_exception

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I have a filter with painless in Elasticsearch query which returns me error

"index_out_of_bounds_exception"

strange thing is that it gives also result[image]

Here is the script

```
    {
       "query": {
        "bool": {
         "must": [
          {
            "term" : {
              "type": {
                "value" : 2
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "term" : {
              "channels": {
                "value" : 94
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "term" : {
              "active": {
                "value" : true
              }
            }
          }
        ], 
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": """
            int successCount = 2; 
            int successIndex = 0; 
            int oneCombinationSuccessCount0 = 1; 
            int index0 = 0; 
            def productFound0 = false; 
            for (c in doc['collection']){ 
              int oneCombinationSuccessIndex0 = 0; 
              def cKey = index0 + '_index'; 
              def key = 'creativeCollectionProperties.'+cKey; 
              if (!productFound0) { 
                if (doc.containsKey(key+'.product_category') && doc[key+'.product_category'].size() > 0) { 
                  if ((doc[key+'.product_category'].value == 131784 || doc[key+'.product_category'].contains(Long.parseLong(131784.toString())))) {
                    oneCombinationSuccessIndex0 += 1; 
                    
                  } 
                  
                } 
                index0+=1; 
                if (oneCombinationSuccessIndex0 >= oneCombinationSuccessCount0) { 
                  successIndex += 1; productFound0 = true; 
                  
                } 
                
              } 
              
            } 
            int oneCombinationSuccessCount1 = 2; 
            int index1 = 0; 
            def productFound1 = false; 
            for (c in doc['collection']){ 
              int oneCombinationSuccessIndex1 = 0; 
              def cKey = index1 + '_index'; 
              def key = 'creativeCollectionProperties.'+cKey; 
              if (!productFound1) { 
                if (doc.containsKey(key+'.product_category') && doc[key+'.product_category'].size() > 0) { 
                  if ((doc[key+'.product_category'].value == 5818 || doc[key+'.product_category'].contains(Long.parseLong(5818.toString())))) {
                    oneCombinationSuccessIndex1 += 1; 
                    
                  }
                  
                } 
                if (doc.containsKey(key+'.generated_color') && doc[key+'.generated_color'].size() > 0) { if ((doc[key+'.generated_color'].value == 123324 || doc[key+'.generated_color'].contains(Long.parseLong(123324.toString())))) {
                  oneCombinationSuccessIndex1 += 1; 
                  
                } 
                  
                } 
                index1+=1; 
                if (oneCombinationSuccessIndex1 >= oneCombinationSuccessCount1) { 
                  successIndex += 1; productFound1 = true; 
                  
                } 
                
              } 
              
            } 
            if (successIndex >= successCount) { 
              return true; 
              
            } 
            
            return false;
          """
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Of my 5 shards, 4 are successful and 1 is a failure. Do you have an idea because of what it can be? I need it very much because the Elasticsearch client which I am using gives an error if any failures came. I have other indexes also with the same structure like this but only here this error giving, others working as expected.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please post your script and sample  document. you can check your script where you are trying to access value of field or array and there you can put null or size 0 check condition. It is giving you result from other shards where it is executing without any issue.

Comment: @peter thanks for the answer. script and document are very long to put here in a comment. I prepared screenshots

script: https://prnt.sc/5f1MwTIXzBiD
the document which should return a result:  https://prnt.sc/J9N_6XprKi-J https://prnt.sc/sOZCbhYTahzG 

document was long I put inside 2 screenshots, thanks a lot

Comment: You can edit your question and put script.

Comment: @peter script is in question

Comment: @peter I see that you did some changes but can't see where? or did I mess something?

Comment: I have added proper formatting to your question.

Comment: @peter ok thanks a lot. do you know any idea what I can do to solve it?